# arduino uno + GSM sim900

Tags: arduino, gsm, gprs, sim900

I need some guidance for making LED ON-OFF using Arduino Uno and GSM SIM900 with the help of internet data. Also how to setup free hosting server so that I can communicate my arduino with android app.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please write a more precise question and show some effort yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: set GPRS Commands(ie APN) of SIM900

Step 2: set tcp ip connection to your static server and port number(AT command is given in manual. static IP is must)

step 3: When TCP/IP connection gets ready, send command from server(use Hercules software) to your device to on/off led.

step 4: read server's command from your arduino and make led on/off.

I hope it help.